# Using Odbc driver query given result in database but not filling datatable in c#, there is no error

Tags: c#, oracle, dns, odbc

Just started using windows 11 and installed Oracle drivers for 32Bit and 64Bit, wrote program using C# to fetch data from Oracle database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
 
namespace ApexAutoEmailConsol
{
    static class ServiceLog
    {
        static String connectionString = "Dsn=Prod21_32;uid=ebseb;pwd=ebseb";
        static string strQuery = string.Empty;
         
        public static string OutstandingInvoices()
        {
            try
            {
                OdbcConnection oCon = new OdbcConnection();
                oCon.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                oCon.Open();

                DataTable dtSales = new DataTable();

                strQuery = "SELECT * from apps.org_organization_definitions HO";
               // if I run above query in Toad it's giving result.
                OdbcDataAdapter myAdp = new OdbcDataAdapter(strQuery, oCon);
                myAdp.Fill(dtSales);
                
                //Adapter not filling data to the datatable.
                if (dtSales.Rows.Count <= 0)
                {
                    return "";
                }
 
                return strReturn;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                WriteErrorLog(Ex.ToString());
                return "";
            }
        }    
}
```

When I copy `strQuery` and run on Toad, getting result but datatable is still empty.

What is the problem? The same code is working perfect on my Windows10 machine.

Comment: Did you make sure that the code in `catch` block is not executed?

Comment: Why do you import `System.Data.SqlClient` which is the driver for MS SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data from another session (C#) then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client (Toad).

If you have issued a `COMMIT` and still can't see the data then make sure that both the SQL Client (Toad) and the C# program are connecting to the same database and are querying the same user's schema of that database.

Comment: Sorted problem by adding following environment variable. NLS_LANG = American_America.UTF8

Answer (score 0):

It's very unique problem, I had it around 2 years ago with my another machine, where I was not able to get some query result in Toad. Some queries are working but some of with specific table in joing was giving empty result. That time I added following language setting in my environment variable and was worked.
**NLS_LANG = American_America.UTF8**

Used same in my new machine and now am getting result with Visual Studio 2022.